# Spring Boot 3 + Flyway + Postgres 9.5

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, flyway, postgresql-9.5

We are currently upgrading our Spring Boot based application to version 3 but the following issue occurs:

1. **Spring Boot 3** uses Flyway in version 9.
2. We need to support our database which is Postgres 9.5, but **Flyway Community** in version 9 does not have support for Postgres 9.5.

Is there any way to use **Spring Boot 3** + **Flyway Community** + **Postgres** that is not supported by Flyway Community (in our case 9.5)?

Answer (score 3):

Spring Boot 3 will only auto-configure Flyway if it is at least version 8 or higher. You can use Spring Boot 3 with older Flyway versions if you disable the auto-configuration and do the configuration yourself.

There are multiple ways to disable the auto-configuration of Flyway:

- You can pass `FlywayAutoConfiguration.class` to the field `exclude` of the annotation `@SpringBootApplication` (or `@EnableAutoConfiguration`),
- you can set the property `spring.flyway.enabled` to `false`, or
- you can expose a bean of type `Flyway` such that the auto-configuration backs off.

If the auto-configuration of Spring Boot 2 worked fine for you, then I'd recommend the last approach. You can take the code of `FlywayAutoConfiguration` from Spring Boot 2, remove the stuff that's specific for auto-configuration classes (e.g. every annotation whose name starts with `Conditional`), and put it in your own code as a normal configuration class annotated with `@Configuration`. This class will then expose at least a bean of type `Flyway` to let the auto-configuration back off and a bean of type `FlywayMigrationInitializer` that performs the actual migrations.

Comment: 3rd is a bit hacky, isn't it?

Comment: Spring Boot is about convention over configuration but doesn't force its conventions and opinions on you. Auto-configurations are such conventions and are designed to get out of your way if they don't work for you and you do your own configuration. The 3rd way is actually how Spring Boot is intended to be used.